Identify part number of photointerrupter
I repair Canon L lenses and am looking to replace a part that I am unable to identify. I am convinced it is a photointerrupter and it looks very similar to the Rohm RPI-441C1 (website: https://www.rohm.com/products/optical-sensors/transmission-type-photointerrupters/rpi-441c1-product) but the dimensions are not correct. It might be discontinued, since the lens I'm repairing is over 16 years old. I'm happy to buy anything that works, as long as the dimensions are accurate and the PCB works with it.
The photointerrupter is part of the autofocus assembly. A clear slotted plastic strip (not shown) passes through it, telling the PCB what the rotation of the focus assembly is.
I have not measured the voltage or diodes. I do have a simple multimeter, but limited knowledge of using it.
Dimensions (approximate, my calipers are not very accurate):
Width: 8 mm
Slot width: 3.0-3.5 mm
Height (excl pins): 3.8-4.0 mm
Depth: 3.8-4.0 mm
Aperture: <= 0.5 mm
The last picture shows the plastic assembly in which it sits.






It's usually called a slotted optical switch; you can find many models if you google for that term. Look for a thru-hole version with the same dimensions; it may just happen to have the same electrical properties as well.

slide the sensor and the LED out of the enclosure, part numbers may be visible

Thanks for the suggestions.
@Paul I checked online but found the same results as I did for photointerrupter. There are many available, but I haven't found one with the same dimensions.
jsotola - I just did, but the sensor and LED unfortunately do not have any markings on them
